# Heroku push rake assets fail suddenly using precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I get an error when I do a 'git push heroku master'.
I compile assets locally using:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

The thing is, this has been working regularly over the last few months and only yesterday did something decide to fail.

I also tried the following to recompile from scratch with same result:

```
rake assets:clobber --trace
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

Not sure how to debug this. My most recent check-in looks reasonable (i.e. I was not editing configuration files or rakefile etc.).  I was changing some png images alright (new images, resizing images) but precompiling locally does not seem to show any errors.

Here is the start of the error message.

```
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a612be38eac01922e9ad7a0a8c37a351/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.4.10/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:83: warning: else without rescue is useless
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     SyntaxError: /tmp/build_a612be38eac01922e9ad7a0a8c37a351/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.4.10/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:79: syntax error, unexpected '.'
remote:  !     from ||= if defined? Rails&.respond_to?(:root) && Rails&.root
remote:  !     ^
remote:  !     /tmp/build_a612be38eac01922e9ad7a0a8c37a351/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-9.4.10/lib/autoprefixer-rails/processor.rb:79: syntax error, unexpected '.'
remote:  !     from ||= if defined? Rails&.respond_to?(:root) && Rails&.root
remote:  !     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, this problem went away after spending a full day trying to fix/research it. Next day everything worked and I've no idea why. The last thing I did was comment out a line in my production.rb, build everything and then uncomment it back in. Not sure if it was related at all. FYI the line was:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['landing.js', 'landing.css']
```